# Excel Formula Assigning Parent Part Number to a Child

Tags: excel-formula, formula, byte-order-mark

I am looking for someone to help me out with a code that once worked but now doesn't and I can't figure out what went wrong.
Here is a link to the work sheet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au53oWRKuRfD9kanfyQ62uW30r1V

In worksheet 1 (Engineering Release) we will this out and it populates sheet 2 (BOMUploadRelease). In sheet 2 the parent column should populate the parent part number from sheet 1 and concatenate the part number based off the dispo on sheet 1 similar to column A on sheet 2. The number of rows should be the same with part data on both sheets 1 and 2 and everything else to be blank below them. All other columns are working perfectly except the Parent column in sheet 2.

Here is the code for the Parent column is sheet 2 as of now:

```
=LET(PART_ORIG, A2, 
PART, IFERROR(MID(PART_ORIG, 1, FIND(".", PART_ORIG)-1), PART_ORIG),
DISPO, 'Engineering Release'!$K$6:$K$62,
OUTLINE,'Engineering Release'!$A$6:$A$62,
PARTS, 'Engineering Release'!$B$6:$B$62,
PARENT, IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND(".", OUTLINE))), OUTLINE,LEFT(OUTLINE, LEN(OUTLINE)-2)),
IDENTIFY_PARENT, XLOOKUP(PART, PARTS, PARENT, "Error 1", 0),
PARENT_PART, XLOOKUP(IDENTIFY_PARENT, OUTLINE, PARTS, "Error 2", 0),
IDENTIFY_DISO, XLOOKUP(IDENTIFY_PARENT, OUTLINE,DISPO, "Error 3", 0),
TEXT(IF(IDENTIFY_DISO="Repair",CONCATENATE(PARENT_PART,".R"),IF(IDENTIFY_DISO="Reuse", CONCATENATE(PARENT_PART,".U"), IF(IDENTIFY_DISO="Modify", CONCATENATE(PARENT_PART,".M"), IF(IDENTIFY_DISO="Ref.", CONCATENATE(PARENT_PART,".REF"), IF(IDENTIFY_DISO="New",CONCATENATE(PARENT_PART, ".N"), ""))))),"0"))
```

Sheet 1:
Gets filled out and we use the item number (column A) to determine which part number is a parent or child of another, For example in the table below 1 would be the top parent, 1.1 & 1.2 would be a child of 1, and 1.1.1 would be a child of 1.1. Column B we list the actual part number of the part we are working on, Column K we dispo the part Repair, New, Reuse, Modify, and Reference in order to know what we are doing with the part. Sheet 1 would look something like this:

| Sheet 1 Column A Item | Sheet 1 Column B Part Number | Sheet 1 Column K Dispo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123-456 | New |
| 1.1 | 234-789 | Repair |
| 1.1.1 | A-458-461-78A | Modify |
| 1.2 | B-234-235-146 | Reuse |

Sheet 2 (BOMUploadRelease):
In column A we use the part number from column A on sheet 1 and add a "." and up to 3 letters based off the dispo on sheet 1 for the name of the BOM so in our system we know what is a part number and what is a BOM Router Number. In Column S on sheet 2 we list the parent BOM Name in the row of the child. Sheet 2 should look like something like this based off of sheet 1:

| Sheet 2 Column A BOM Name | Sheet 2 Column O BOM Level | Sheet 2 Column S Parent BOM Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123-456.N | 0 |  |
| 234-789.R | 1 | 123-456.N |
| A-458-461-78A.M | 2 | 234-789.R |
| B-234-235-146.U | 1 | 123-456.N |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post sample data as markdown table, so that we don't need to open a file to understand the question and logic. This way this will not help others that may be looking for solution to a similar problem: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Just the last column I need fixed to show what it looks like in the example right now it throws errors after the very top row but yes just the parent column code is what I need fixed. The code to the parent column or the last column in sheet too in the example is posted above

Comment: So on sheet 2 the child row should have the parent part number in column parent and then concatenate the end based off the Dispo on sheet 1. I am out of the office right now and can check tomorrow. You can try it in the link I sent. So the code I have goes through and checks based off the item number What Child is to what parent and then it pulls the part number from sheet 1 and brings it into sheet too and matches the part number from the child and puts the parent part number to the parent column and then adds the dot and letters based off the Dispo on sheet 1.

Comment: I think this might be what you're after: `=LET(x,XLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,7),Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4),IFERROR(XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(x,"."),Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4&"."&LEFT(Sheet1!$F$1:$F$4)),""))`

Comment: I will try it tonight from home when im off my second job. I will let you know.

Comment: @ P.b. that code does not work. It returns blanks.

Comment: Correct I am using excel. Let me make another post in an answer on here so I can maybe explain a little more. give me like 15 mins.

Comment: Please See my edited post under the code above in the original post. We were using a Xlookup with a 62 row range on each so the sheet is automated. The Sheet can have up to 62 lines.

Comment: I see, before I start, is the parent always listed in the Sheet you want the result in? In other words, can we lookup in the result sheet itself to the level minus 1?

Comment: Yes the Parent is in column A of sheet 2, the results should go in column S of sheet 2. The levels in sheet 2 column O show 0 if it is the top level parent, 1 if it is the first child of a top level parent, 2 is it is a child of a child, 3 if it is a child of a child of a child, etc. The level does not determine who the parent is.... Sheet 1 column A determines who the parent is.

Comment: So would this do? `=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(O2-1,$O$2:$O2,$A$2:$A2,""),"")` in `S2`

Comment: That works for the first children of the main parent and the first child of the child but not the second child of the child. The levels in the second sheet doesn't determine the parent. Column A in sheet 1 determines the parent. See the screen shot in the end of the original post to see the results.

Comment: I'll look into it later today

Comment: `=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(O2-1,$O$2:$O2,$A$2:$A2,"",,-1),"")` if the data in your 2nd sheet is always in this order

Comment: It is not always in that order. To determine the parent you need to go off of column a in sheet one. The parent child relationship is based of that column. The column O in sheet 2 is telling you what level of the part is as a child but does not determine which parent, each child goes to.... Column a in sheet one does this if you remove the last number and period and match the result to the parent in column a on sheet 1.

Comment: Your code works like you said as long as it is in the correct order every time. Technically it should be in the correct order every single time but I want to account for human error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, this would work with examples shared
`=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(O2-1,$O$2:$O2,$A$2:$A2,"",,-1),"")`

But if you need to obtain the values from the other sheet, you could use this formula:

```
=LET(x, XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(A2,".",-1),
        'Engineering Release'!$B$6:$B$10,
        'Engineering Release'!$A$6:$A$10),
     y, 'Engineering Release'!$K$6:$K$10,
IFERROR( XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(x,".",-1),
                 TEXT('Engineering Release'!$A$6:$A$10,"@"),
                 'Engineering Release'!$B$6:$B$10
                 &"."
                 &IFS(y="Ref.","REF",                   
                      y="Repair","R",                    
                      y="Reuse","U",                   
                      y="Modify","M",                    
                      y="new","N")),
         ""))
```

[image]

The challenge was that the values in `Engineering Release` column A was mix of text and numbers. I have this converted in the formula, so it works with your data, but it's good practice to store all as text in the first place, so we don't need a formula to convert it.

Comment: The first code in this answer works. I appreciate your help. I have instructed the employees that are filling out the sheet to make sure everything is in order and that they fill the sheet out correctly in order to avoid mistakes. I am accepting the first code as the answer, unfortunately I cannot get the second code in the answer to work.... I only get blanks.

Comment: You should have it working in the file you shared https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au53oWRKuRfD9kanfyQ62uW30r1V also refer to screenshot

Comment: I just checked... it worked on the web version but when I downloaded it and updated the excel document it quit working and went blank. It worked perfectly until i downloaded the file.

Comment: Weird.. can't explain

Comment: Yeah me neither. Again thank you for your help. Right now it works so when i get time i will try to figure out how to get it to work with your second code in your answer.